# How to use Otherwise with AngularJs ui-route

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to handle page not found with Angular ui-router and "otherwise".

When I click on anchor link of the markup, I have the next error:

```
Error: Could not resolve '/erro' from state 'errorpage'
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3248)
    at Object.go (angular-ui-router.js:3176)
    at angular-ui-router.js:4267
    at angular.js:19916
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:6111)
    at angular.js:6390
```

Here is my code:

markup:

```
 <li><a ui-sref='/erro'>DashBoard</a></li>
 <li><a ui-sref='/erro'>Caixa</a></li>
```

angular app.js:

```
    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
            var $state = $injector.get('$state');

            $state.go('errorpage', {
                title: "Page not found",
                message: 'Could not find a state associated with url "'+$location.$$url+'"'
            });
        });
      $stateProvider
        .state('errorpage',{
          url: "*path",
          template:'<div>{{title}}-{{message}}</div>'
        })  

.........

continues
```

Comment: `ui-sref` does not accept the url to the route. It accepts the name of the state.

Comment: @Ben Beck OK, but if I change to ui-sref='erro', there is no difference . The error is the same.